# My bibliography header calls itself index of abbreviations?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, acronyms

I have a little problem and I can't seem to find a solution.

I have an index of abbreviations and a bibliography. The index of abbreviations should be called *Abkürzungsverzeichnis* and the bibliography *Literatur*.

However, whenever I use the index of abbreviations, the title of my bibliography changes to *Abkürzungsverzeichnis*, which I don't want.

```
\documentclass[man, apacite, floatsintext, 12pt, donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acronym} 
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs,caption}

\title{xx}
\author{xx}
\affiliation{xx}
\date{April 2016}
\shorttitle{xx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage

\renewcommand \refname{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}     
\section{Abkürzungsverzeichnis} 

\begin{acronym}[asldkfjasdöfihasodöfhsodfhösa]
\acro{QCAE}{Questionnaire of Cognitive and Affective Empathy}
\acro{NPI-R}{Narcissistic Personality Inventory - Revised}
\acro{TCI}{Temperament and Character Inventory}
\acro{LSRP}{Levenson's Self-Report Psychopathy Scale}
\end{acronym}




\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\bibliography{sample}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not sure I understood your question completly, but for me it seems that your used "command" `\renewcommand \refname{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}` is your problem.

Please see the following MWE (I added an example bibliography and commented your command `\renewcommand \refname{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}`):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[%
  man, apacite, floatsintext, 12pt, donotrepeattitle
]{apa6}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acronym} 
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs,caption}

\title{xx}
\author{xx}
\affiliation{xx}
\date{April 2016}
\shorttitle{xx}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage

%\renewcommand \refname{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}     

\section{Abkürzungsverzeichnis} 
\begin{acronym}[asldkfjasdöfihasodöfhsodfhösa]
\acro{QCAE}{Questionnaire of Cognitive and Affective Empathy}
\acro{NPI-R}{Narcissistic Personality Inventory - Revised}
\acro{TCI}{Temperament and Character Inventory}
\acro{LSRP}{Levenson's Self-Report Psychopathy Scale}
\end{acronym}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname} % to use bib file created by filecontents

\end{document}
```

with the result you want to get:

[image: Abkürzungsverzeichnis]

and with the bibliography:

[image: Literatur]